# How to create msi and install from it?

Tags: windows, installation, debian, windows-installer

Is it correct msi file is the Windows equivalence of deb file in Debian?

In Debian/Ubuntu, after I compile a program into an executable, I can create a deb file out of the executable using a program called `checkinstall`. Then I can install a deb file by `dpkg`.

In Windows,

- what is the program/command that can create a msi file from an executable built from source code?
- What is the program/command that can install a msi file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Installer consists of an SDK, database specification and runtime service. Introduced in 1999, it originally had redistributables that were nesseccary to "bootstrap" onto the system before and MSI could be installed.  Various versions of this runtime have been been baked into various versions of Windows for a very long time now  so generally this is no longer a concern.  You can simply install the MSI.

Technically the SDK does come with some tools that could be used to create an MSI.  However this would be like using notepad and CSC to write a .NET app.  Almost no one would actually do it this way.  One notable tool does come from the SDK:  ORCA.exe.  ORCA is a database editor which is very useful for examining MSIs  and making minor modifications to already built MSI.  It technically can be used to create an MSI but very few outside of Microsoft back in the early days ever did.

For the most part Microsoft left installer authoring tools to third parties.  Windows Installer XML (open source), Industrial Strength Windows Installer XML (open source), InstallShield, Visual Studio Deployment Projects, InstallAware and AdavancedInstaller are a few to list.  It is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow but I will link a 2 minute video showing how to use Visual Studio, WiX and IsWiX to create a simple MSI with a shortcut for a single EXE:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnV_OU6fk8c

Disclosure: I'm the project maintainer for the IsWiX on GitHub.

As for how to install an MSI. An MSI is a database not a program.  It is installed by the Windows Installer service msiexec.exe

There is an extensive command line documented at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Christopher! That is clear. I was wondering if you could answer my another question [Is Windows Installer   a package manager, or a general-purposed installer? What is the difference between a package manager and a general-purposed installer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1209143/windows-installer-general-purposed-installer-or-package-manager)  Thanks.

Comment: Windows Installer is a general purpose installer for the Windowns desktop/server platform.  Windows doesn't really have a native package manager.  There are some bolt on attempts like choco.

Comment: Thanks. What makes Windows Installer not a package manager? if possible, you could reply there in more details.

Answer (score -1):

There is no standard tool for creating MSI installer files. There are many, many third-party tools, free and paid, that will help you to create MSIs; you'll have to do some searching and comparing and figure out what works best for you. The command to install an MSI is the MSI itself, you don't need to explicitly run it with any other program like you do with deb/rpm packages.

Comment: I heard that MSI is a database file. So I think it is not an executable, but an input file for an executable i.e. an installer. Am i right?

Comment: Under the covers, it might be; I don't know for sure if it executes directly and uses the Windows Installer service, or if it's technically a file opened by Windows Installer. From a user perspective though, an MSI can be run the same as an EXE.

Comment: Is a MSI file really an executable?

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: An MSI is NOT an executable. An executable does not require any third-party programs to run, whereas an MSI file does. By your reference, a .cmd or .bat file would also be an executable, but they require Command Prompt to be present on the system. .cmd and .bat files are not executables either. Nor are .doc, .jpg, .mp3, etc.

Comment: Where do you draw the line? An EXE can require Windows, .NET, and additional DLLs in order to run.

Comment: For the record, the interpreter that runs MSI executables is `msiexec`.  You may need to refer to it explicitly in some contexts, e.g., if you are launching the installer via CreateProcess().

Comment: Adrian, an MSI is a document / database that has MIME registration pointing back to the windows installer service.  There is a command line programs called msiexe.exe that you can use to perform various operations using an MSI.  There are also COM and Native APIs that can be invoked rather then calling msiexec.exe.  I'd be happy to spend an hour with you on a phone/screenshare to give you an architectural overview of the Windows Installer.  I can see you have an interest in MSI and I can answer any questions you might have.